# How to extract a portion of a string in R

Tags: r

I have a string "HAD BEEN SEARCHING FOR MY 1ST ANDROID SMARTPHONE FOR OVER 6 MONTHS. WITH BUDGET OF 10K WAS ALL SET TO BUY MMX 110 BUT THEN THOUGHT TO WAIT FOR MMX 116. BUT WITH MMX 116 AT 16K, I TOO HAD TO INCREASE MY BUDGET FROM 15K AND STARTED TO LOOK OUT FOR OTHER SMARTPHONE OPTIONS FROM SAMSUNG, IPHONE, HTC ETC."

I want to extract only those portions which contain the word "SMARTPHONE". The portions must lie within two full stops or two commas. A combination of comma and full stop will also do.

I tried the R code

y=grep("[,.]?[[:alnum:]]+(SMARTPHONE)[[:alnum:]]+[,.]",x,perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)

but it is not giving me the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you want to split on all commas and full stop and then see if each element contains SMARTPHONE?

See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) for splitting strings. And then [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pmatch.html) for partial string matching.

One thing to beware of is splitting on the 'period', which would split after abbreviations, such as Mr.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
> a <- "HAD BEEN SEARCHING FOR MY 1ST ANDROID SMARTPHONE FOR OVER 6 MONTHS. WITH BUDGET OF 10K WAS ALL SET TO BUY MMX 110 BUT THEN THOUGHT TO WAIT FOR MMX 116. BUT WITH MMX 116 AT 16K, I TOO HAD TO INCREASE MY BUDGET FROM 15K AND STARTED TO LOOK OUT FOR OTHER SMARTPHONE OPTIONS FROM SAMSUNG, IPHONE, HTC ETC."
> b <- unlist(strsplit(a, "[,.]"))
> (c <- b[grep("SMARTPHONE", b)])
[1] "HAD BEEN SEARCHING FOR MY 1ST ANDROID SMARTPHONE FOR OVER 6 MONTHS"                                         
[2] " I TOO HAD TO INCREASE MY BUDGET FROM 15K AND STARTED TO LOOK OUT FOR OTHER SMARTPHONE OPTIONS FROM SAMSUNG"
```

Comment: Nice implementation. One thing to point out is that splitting on '.' will also split on abbreviations.

Comment: No, my problem is not solved exactly. Is there any way I can use regex for extracting only a portion of string? Splitting will destroy the structure in other cases. Somehow, I am not getting the result using grep, regexpr etc.

Comment: @user3350235, you need to be more precise about the desired result. My example gives  you the portions that are delignated by comma or fullstop and contain the string 'SMARTPHONE' as described in the OP..

Comment: @philshem,  I don't know of an regex that can destinguish abbreviations from the end of a sentence.

Comment: @kay it's a problem for all natural language processing, in all languages. how to differentiate between a full stop and an abbreviation. things were easier when two spaces came after a full stop ;)